# Multiple URL are not opening from anchor tag by using window.open in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I am trying to open multiple URL in one click by using window.open but In Safari only one URL is opened in new tab other not.

Safari version is 11.0.1.

```
onclick="window.open('URL1','_blank');window.open('URL2','_blank');window.open('URL3','_blank');"
```

Comment: i tried it in mozila,chrome,safari and IE. none of them opening three tabs. So i am unable to reproduce your problem (i have added proper URLS THERE)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have checked this in firefox(56.0) and it's opening 3 tabs. But in chrome and safari only 1 tab is opening. How can I resolve this in safari and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The pop up blocker in Chrome prevents opening multiple windows from one click. I assume Safari is the same. Firefox is more lenient but (I believe) there must be a user click to start with.

Hopefully you will not be able to resolve this - by design allowing multiple tabs to be opened from a single click has been prevented.